# Leaders Lead By Solutions

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Is it a possible sentence?

Leaders Lead By Solutions.

Comment: It's grammatically the same as "leaders lead by example", but doesn't actually mean anything. Maybe you mean "leaders lead by creating solutions" or something similar, but I can't really know.

Comment: Yes I mean that "leaders lead by providing solutions". But I wanted the sentence short like "leaders lead by example".

Comment: I wonder if we really need to use the plural form of *solutions* here, especially when SAP have their SAP Training & Education by Solution.

Comment: Can you give context? (like a URL to the article you found this)

Comment: No article Mitch. I'm writing this myself and stuck :)

Comment: Damkerng, I think about this too.. Solution or Solutions. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Leaders Lead with Solutions

Comment: Why do you think it may not be a possible sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance this may seem similar to:

> Leaders lead by example.

However, *by example* is an idiomatic use that stands as its own meaning. We know what the leader is doing regarding "examples", they are being that example (or in the verb sense, they are *exampling* the qualities desired, but that verb sense is now very rare). It also compares with some other idiomatic uses such as "prove by example", "demonstrate by example".

This idiomatic use owes a lot to direct translation from Latin expressions, hence it not working quite as we might otherwise expect.

For this reason, if you try to use another noun in the same way, we don't know what the connection between that noun and their leadership is; are they creating solutions, offering them, demanding them?

You would have to provide the gerund of the verb for the activity they lead by:

> Leaders lead by providing solutions.
>
> Leaders lead by solving.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the detail explanation and the two sentences.. I would love to chose "Leaders lead by solving." Thank you so much to lead :)

Comment: I just would like to ask you.. if I want to make the sentence, "leaders lead by solving.. not by blaming others." Is it ok?

Comment: The only objection there is the two dots. I suspect you meant for ellipsis, which is three dots (`...` or `…` as a single character). I'd prefer just a comma myself: *Leaders lead by solving, not by blaming.* Removing "others" there isn't a correction, just aiming at making it punchier, we normally would including the object with *blaming* but leaving it out is allowed in some cases, and I gather a short punchy expression is what you are aiming at. You might find http://ell.stackexchange.com/ good as well as this site, aiming more at simpler usage questions.

Comment: Thanks for understanding what exactly I want. "Leaders lead by solving, not by blaming." is good enough. Thank you so much Jon, for your help.

Answer (score 2):

"By" in the sense you are using is almost always followed by an action: "Leaders lead by solving problems." However, you could say "Leaders lead *with* solutions," although that's still a bit clunky.

There are exceptions of course, usually from idioms. Consider: "Leaders lead by example."

Comment: I actually quite like 'Leaders lead with solutions.'  Doesn't seem clunky to me.  +1

Comment: "Leaders lead with solutions." This was in my 2nd thought.. Thanks Caerulius!.. but as you say bit clunky. But mikeY says it's fine :D Thank you so much for your answer :)

Comment: Plus, it's got the "lead with" idiom working, "lead with" as in "offer first".